# Parameter Optimization with Custom indicators - Quantstrat

Tags: r, optimization, quantstrat, technical-indicator

I am looking for examples of Parameter optimization codes in Quantstrat when using **custom indicators**.
Most of the examples I can find online use SMA, MACD and other classic indicators. It doesn't help me much as I'd like mostly to optmize trading systems with custom indicators.

Does anyone have relevant links or material ?

To be more specific, I am trying for the first time the indicator optimization option. The indicator I am using is the momentum of the MACD forest . I'm trying to assess the effectiveness of this indicator vs. the usual MACD crossing signal line.
But I don't want to focus too much on this specific indicator as the goal for me is to have a viable optimization code for future custom indicators I'll be using.

Here is the code, the data is intraday EURUSD quotes (5 mins candles) :

```
library(quantstrat)


Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

currency(c('EUR', 'USD'))

exchange_rate(c('EURUSD'), tick_size=0.0001)


init_date <- "2018-01-07"
start_date <- "2018-01-08"
end_date <- "2018-01-08"
init_equity <- 1e8 # $100,000,000
adjustment <- FALSE

basic_symbols <- function() {
  symbols <- c(
       "EUR" 
      )
}

  symbols <- basic_symbols()


portfolio.st <- "Port.Luxor.Opt"  
account.st <- "Acct.Luxor.Opt"
strategy.st <- "Strat.Luxor.Opt"

rm.strat(portfolio.st)   
rm.strat(account.st)

initPortf(name = portfolio.st, 
          symbols = symbols,
          initDate = init_date)

initAcct(name = account.st,
         portfolios = portfolio.st,
         initDate = init_date,
         initEq = init_equity)

initOrders(portfolio = portfolio.st,
           symbols = symbols,
           initDate = init_date)

strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE) 

fastMA_custom = 12
fastMA_custom2 = 12
slowMA_custom = 26
slowMA_custom2 = 26
signalMA_custom = 9
signalMA_custom2 = 9
maType="EMA"
MAforest = 3

forest <- function(x){
  step1 <- EMA(x,fastMA_custom)
  step2 <- EMA(x,slowMA_custom)
  step3 <- step1-step2
  step4 <- EMA(step3,signalMA_custom)
  step5 <- step3-step4
  return(step5)
}

smaforest <- function(x){
  step1 <- EMA(x,fastMA_custom2)
  step2 <- EMA(x,slowMA_custom2)
  step3 <- step1-step2
  step4 <- EMA(step3,signalMA_custom2)
  step5 <- step3-step4
  step6 <- EMA(step5,MAforest)
  return(step6)
}

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name ="forest",
              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))),
              label="forest")

add.indicator(strategy=strategy.st,
              name ="smaforest",
              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))),
              label="smaforest")

add.distribution(strategy.st,
                 paramset.label = "forestopt",
                 component.type = "indicator",
                 component.label = "forest",
                 variable = list(fastMA_custom= 8:14),
                 label = "fastMA_custom")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("forest", "smaforest"),
                            relationship = "gte"),
           label = "long")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("forest", "smaforest"),
                            relationship = "lte"),
           label = "short")

add.rule(strategy.st,
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 100000,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterLONG")

add.rule(strategy.st,
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "short",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = -100000,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "short", 
                          replace = FALSE, 
                          TxnFees = -1
                          ),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterSHORT")

add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "short", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "long", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "Exit2SHORT")


add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "short", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "Exit2LONG")

addPosLimit(portfolio.st, 'EUR', timestamp=initDate, maxpos=500, minpos=0)


resultsopt <- apply.paramset(strategy.st,
                          paramset.label = "forestopt",
                          portfolio.st = portfolio.st,
                          account.st = account.st, 
                          nsamples = 0)
```

The backtesting without the optimization part works perfectly. It's really the optimization bit that causes the error.

Here is the error I get :

> error calling combine function: "simpleError in fun(result.1,
>   result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6,     result.7):
>   attempt to select less than one element"

Comment: optimisation works exactly the same way with custom indicator functions.  You haven't provided much effort/detail.  Why dont you give an example of code, showing what your problem is with trying to get a custom indicator to work.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have inserted one example of optimization code that returns an error.

Comment: *"Does anyone have relevant links or material ?"* For further examples of optimisation in quantstrat, you'll find quite a few examples on SO.  Search with "[quantstrat]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a reproducible data set next time.

Here is sample code very similar to yours that does work on optimising a custom indicator.  Hope it becomes clear how you should adjust your code.  You're doing a few things incorrectly.  In particular, you must supply the formal arguments to `forest`, or any other custom function you want to optimise in quantstrat.  Generally it's a bad idea to define all your "n" variables globally by default.  Supply them directly into the arguments in the `add.indicator` call.  Just like what is done below for the `forest` function.

```
library(quantstrat)


Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

currency(c('USD'))

symbols <- "AAPL"
getSymbols(symbols)

stock(symbols, currency = "USD")


AAPL <- AAPL["2016/"]

init_date <- "2017-01-07"
start_date <- "2018-01-31"
end_date <- "2018-01-31"
init_equity <- 1e8 # $100,000,000
adjustment <- FALSE


portfolio.st <- "Luxor.Opt"  
account.st <- "Luxor.Opt"
strategy.st <- "Luxor.Opt"

rm.strat(name = portfolio.st)   

initPortf(name = portfolio.st, 
          symbols = symbols)

initAcct(name = account.st,
         portfolios = portfolio.st,
         initEq = init_equity)

initOrders(portfolio = portfolio.st,
           symbols = symbols)

strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE) 


fastMA_custom2 = 12

slowMA_custom2 = 26

signalMA_custom2 = 9
maType="EMA"
MAforest = 3

forest <- function(x, fastMA_custom, slowMA_custom, signalMA_custom){
  step1 <- EMA(x,fastMA_custom)
  step2 <- EMA(x,slowMA_custom)
  step3 <- step1-step2
  step4 <- EMA(step3,signalMA_custom)
  step5 <- step3-step4
  return(step5)
}

smaforest <- function(x){
  step1 <- EMA(x,fastMA_custom2)
  step2 <- EMA(x,slowMA_custom2)
  step3 <- step1-step2
  step4 <- EMA(step3,signalMA_custom2)
  step5 <- step3-step4
  step6 <- EMA(step5,MAforest)
  return(step6)
}

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
              name ="forest",
              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)),
                               fastMA_custom = 12,
                               slowMA_custom = 26,
                               signalMA_custom = 9
                               ),
              label="forest")

add.indicator(strategy=strategy.st,
              name ="smaforest",
              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))),
              label="smaforest")


add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("forest", "smaforest"),
                            relationship = "gte"),
           label = "long")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st,
           name="sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("forest", "smaforest"),
                            relationship = "lte"),
           label = "short")

add.rule(strategy.st,
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = 100000,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterLONG")

add.rule(strategy.st,
         name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "short",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = -100000,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "short", 
                          replace = FALSE, 
                          TxnFees = -1
         ),
         type = "enter",
         label = "EnterSHORT")

add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "short", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "long", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "Exit2SHORT")


add.rule(strategy.st, 
         name = "ruleSignal", 
         arguments = list(sigcol = "long", 
                          sigval = TRUE, 
                          orderside = "short", 
                          ordertype = "market", 
                          orderqty = "all", 
                          TxnFees = -1, 
                          replace = TRUE), 
         type = "exit", 
         label = "Exit2LONG")

addPosLimit(portfolio.st, symbols[], timestamp=init_date, maxpos=500, minpos=0)

# applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolio.st)
# 
# updatePortf(portfolio.st)
# tradeStats(portfolio.st, symbols)


# Portfolio Symbol Num.Txns Num.Trades Net.Trading.PL Avg.Trade.PL Med.Trade.PL Largest.Winner Largest.Loser Gross.Profits Gross.Losses Std.Dev.Trade.PL Std.Err.Trade.PL Percent.Positive Percent.Negative Profit.Factor
# AAPL Luxor.Opt   AAPL      127         63       -45123.5    -28493.01     -46000.1        1328999      -1047001      10371975    -12167035           474783         59817.04         42.85714         57.14286     0.8524653
# Avg.Win.Trade Med.Win.Trade Avg.Losing.Trade Med.Losing.Trade Avg.Daily.PL Med.Daily.PL Std.Dev.Daily.PL Std.Err.Daily.PL Ann.Sharpe Max.Drawdown Profit.To.Max.Draw Avg.WinLoss.Ratio Med.WinLoss.Ratio Max.Equity Min.Equity
# AAPL      384147.2      305999.5        -337973.2        -298000.6    -28493.01     -46000.1           474783         59817.04  -0.952672     -3182097        -0.01418043           1.13662          1.026842   985976.4   -2196121
# End.Equity
# AAPL   -45123.5

add.distribution(strategy.st,
                 paramset.label = "forestopt",  #The label we will use when we want to run this optimisation in paramset
                 component.type = "indicator", # The custom function is of indicator type (not other alternatives including signal or rule)
                 component.label = "forest", #this is the name of your custom function
                 variable = list(fastMA_custom = seq(8, 12, by = 2)),
                 label = "myForestOptLabel") #choose whatever you want

resultsopt <- apply.paramset(strategy.st,
                             paramset.label = "forestopt",
                             portfolio.st = portfolio.st,
                             account.st = account.st, 
                             nsamples = 0)

# Check, results are equal in the case where fastMA_custom = 12 compared to when running `applyStrategy`:

resultsopt$tradeStats
# myForestOptLabel   Portfolio Symbol Num.Txns Num.Trades Net.Trading.PL Avg.Trade.PL Med.Trade.PL Largest.Winner Largest.Loser Gross.Profits Gross.Losses Std.Dev.Trade.PL Std.Err.Trade.PL Percent.Positive Percent.Negative
# 1                8 Luxor.Opt.1   AAPL       97         48      2609902.7     23790.64    -34500.75        1405999      -1055001       9615975     -8474024         492362.4         71066.39         43.75000         56.25000
# 2               10 Luxor.Opt.2   AAPL      105         52      -340106.5    -34770.27    -52500.75        1405999      -1047001       8538977    -10347031         480790.5         66673.64         40.38462         59.61538
# 3               12 Luxor.Opt.3   AAPL      127         63       -45123.5    -28493.01    -46000.10        1328999      -1047001      10371975    -12167035         474783.0         59817.04         42.85714         57.14286
# Profit.Factor Avg.Win.Trade Med.Win.Trade Avg.Losing.Trade Med.Losing.Trade Avg.Daily.PL Med.Daily.PL Std.Dev.Daily.PL Std.Err.Daily.PL Ann.Sharpe Max.Drawdown Profit.To.Max.Draw Avg.WinLoss.Ratio Med.WinLoss.Ratio Max.Equity
# 1     1.1347590      457903.6      386998.5        -313852.8        -237000.5     23790.64    -34500.75         492362.4         71066.39  0.7670464     -2444032         1.06786773          1.458976          1.632902  3585933.7
# 2     0.8252586      406617.9      334998.1        -333775.2        -245002.2    -34770.27    -52500.75         480790.5         66673.64 -1.1480282     -3152090        -0.10789872          1.218239          1.367327  1343982.9
# 3     0.8524653      384147.2      305999.5        -337973.2        -298000.6    -28493.01    -46000.10         474783.0         59817.04 -0.9526720     -3182097        -0.01418043          1.136620          1.026842   985976.4
# Min.Equity End.Equity
# 1   -1122012  2609902.7
# 2   -1808107  -340106.5
# 3   -2196121   -45123.5

# Results for  fastMA_custom = 12 are identical.
```

Above I also show how you can do a quick check on your `apply.paramsets` output, by comparing it to the individual case via `apply.Strategy` for n = 12.  It's a good idea to do these kinds of checks.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me rewrite the code in a more conventional way. The error is still there though. Even if I copy your code above and run it, I get : " :error calling combine function:simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2, result.3): attempt to select less than one element". Could it be coming from my packages version ?

Comment: The code I have provided works fine after calling `devtools::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")`.  I don't get the error you're describing.

Comment: I updated my packages to newer versions. It worked fine like in your example. Thanks